# While using Material-Ui V5 and createTheme, can themes live in separate directories while having access to each others values?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Instead of having all of my components' themes in a single file, I would like to separate them into directories. Ideally there would be one global theme accessible to all other theme creators.

For example, in my App.js I currently have the following:

```
const globalTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#42a5f5',
        },
    },
});

const headerTheme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiToolbar: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    backgroundColor: globalTheme.palette.primary.main,
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

However, as I add more component themes and overrides, it will become quite large. So I would like to separate them. However, I was unable to find a way to do so while still having access to the `globalTheme` object.

Is this possible to do? If so, what would be the best practice in this case, while avoiding legacy MUI?

Comment: Why don't you just put `globalTheme` in a separate file and reuse it?

Comment: I assume you mean as a ThemeProvider around different components - but this isn't the issue. I could theoretically have all my theming in one giant themeproviding file. But I am wondering if it is possible to split them into different files, because that will be akin to separating components, and more comfortable.

Comment: I mean you can, I don't see why it's the issue here, it's just a variable so you can put it in other files, export and import all of them in the main theme file. The other file contains the style from individual components also depend on `globalTheme` which is just another variable that can be reuseable.

Comment: I'll tell you what the problem is, NearHuscarl. I spent 2 hours testing different import and export options, thinking I'm completely misunderstanding how theming works, and for 2 hours I didn't notice I was making the same typo over and over and over until just now. So the problem is me.

Comment: Glad it works for you.